# How do you set programmatically the Authentication object in Spring Security reactive applications?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

In non reactive applications we could do `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);` to authenticate a request programmatically.

What would be the equivalent with Webflux?

```
public class ReactiveServiceAuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public ReactiveServiceAuthenticationFilter(ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        Mono<Authentication> authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new ReactiveServiceAuthentication(principal, authorization));
        ...
        //Replacement for SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        ...
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. The key was to use the subscriberContext to invoke `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication)`.

```
public class ReactiveServiceAuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public ReactiveServiceAuthenticationFilter(ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        //... In my case I retrieve principal / authorization from headers
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(new ReactiveServiceAuthentication(principal, authorization))
            .flatMap(authentication -> chain.filter(exchange)
                        .subscriberContext(c -> ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication)))
            .onErrorResume(AuthenticationException.class, e -> {
                log.error("Authentication Exception", e);
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but not sure it will work or not:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .flatMap(securityContext -> {
                return authenticationManager.authenticate(new ReactiveServiceAuthentication(principal, authorization))
                   .map(authentication -> {
                       securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
                       return securityContext;
                   }).thenReturn("")
            })
            .defaultIfEmpty("")
            .flatMap(string -> chain.filter(exchange));
}
```

But the best way I think this.
you need extra some class to do this.

SecurityConfig class to create a Bean

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final CustomSecurityContext customSecurityContext;

    public SecurityConfig(ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                          CustomSecurityContext customSecurityContext) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.customSecurityContext = customSecurityContext;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(customSecurityContext)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .build();
    }

}
```

CustomSecurityCOntext class

```
@Component
public class CustomSecurityContext implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public CustomSecurityContext(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange swe, SecurityContext sc) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
        if (CHECK SOMETHING IF YOU WANT TO OTHERWISE NO NEED OF THIS IF) {
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(new ReactiveServiceAuthentication(principal, authorization))
                    .map(SecurityContextImpl::new);
        }

        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

And now in your ReactiveServiceAuthenticationFilter class

```
@Component
public class ReactiveServiceAuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(securityContext -> (String) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal())
                .defaultIfEmpty("")
                .flatMap(principal -> {
                    if (!principal.isEmpty()) 
                        return chain.filter(decorate(exchange, principal)); 
                        // In decorate method check your authentication. 
                        // If not valid then return mono error. 
                        // Otherwise return ServerWebExchange object.
                    else 
                        return chain.filter(exchange);
                });
    }
}
```