# How to configure Spring WebFlux authentication with custom AuthenticationConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

so I was setting up security for my API where you have to log in with username/password obtain JWT token and then use that for everything else.
This is how I set up SecurityWebFilterChain:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/login", "/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterAt(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterAt(bearerAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION);

    return http.build();
}
```

as you can see here, I set up two custom filters. One for username/password and another for Bearer token (JWT).

This is how I set up UsernamePassword filter, where I provide my custom authManager with custom UserDetails service, encoder and successhandler:

```
private AuthenticationWebFilter UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
    UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authManager;
    AuthenticationWebFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;


    authManager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(applicationUserService);
    authManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    successHandler = new  AuthenticationSuccessHandler();

    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager);
    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);

    return usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
}
```

This actually works, I can issue GET request with curl or Postman like this:

```
curl -v  -u username:password localhost:8080/login
```

and get my JWT token back. awesome. Just one problem. By default this filter uses

```
ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter
```

***What I actually want:***
i need to send POST request with username and password in request body in simple JSON structure, like this:

```
{
"username":"usr"
"password":"pass"
}
```

and use that to create Authentication object.

***This is what I tried:***
I created and added custom Converter to my AuthenticationFilter:

```
usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationConverter());
```

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationConverter:

```
public class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationConverter implements ServerAuthenticationConverter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> convert(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is where Im stuck for hours.

***Question1***
 How do I get username/password from JSON body of request and produce `Mono<Authentication>` here? I'm pretty new to reactive programming, sorry if this is stupid question.

***Question2***
Only GET requests seesm to even reach this custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationConverter. Why? any POST requests get rejected before that and I don't understand why.

Comment: What you are building is a custom security implementation which is not best practice. There is no authentication standard which performes authentication by sending a username and password in the body as a POST request and returning a json token. You have been stuck for hours because what you want to do is bad practice and should not be done.

Comment: There are several standards for how authentication should be performed. For example basic authentication, or oauth2s different authentication flows. If you have never done any authentication before i suggest you start out by reading up on `BASIC` authentication and ldo an implementation. After that you move on to looking into oauth authentication and use a predefined token issuer like facebook, google, etc etc

Comment: or look into using any of the predefined oauth2 login alternatives https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login

Comment: you can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397201/how-do-you-set-programmatically-the-authentication-object-in-spring-security-rea/61397519#61397519

Comment: I know sending username/password in request body is not a best practice. As i mentioned, i've got it working when usr/pass are provided as BASIC Authorization header (base64 encoded). I need to use json body because that is external requirements and out of my control.